# Problems with Rounding Decimals (python)

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

In my program, decimal accuracy is very important.
A lot of my calculations must be accurate to many decimal places (such as 50).

Because I am using python, I have been using the decimal module
 (with context().prec = 99. ie;  *Set to have 99 decimal places of accuracy when instantiating a decimal object*)
as pythonic floats don't allow anywhere near such accuracy.

Since I wish for the User to specify the decimal places of accuracy of the calculations, I've had to implement several round() functions in my code.
Unfortuneately, the inbuilt round function and the decimal object do not interact well.

```
round(decimal.Decimal('2.000000000000000000001'),50)

# Number is 1e-21.   There are 21 decimal places, much less than 50.
```

Yet the result is **2.0** instead of **2.000000000000000000001**
The round function is not rounding to 50. Much less!

Yes,  I have made sure that the over-rounding does not occur on instantiation of the Decimal object, but after calling round.
I always pass strings representing floats to the Decimal constructor, never pythonic floats.

Why is the round function doing this to me?
(I realise that it was probably originally designed for pythonic floats which can never have so many decimal places, but the documentation claims that the Decimal object integrates perfectly into python code and is compatible with the inbuilt python functions!)

Thanks profusely!
(This has me quite unnerved, since this problem undermines the use of the entire program)

Specs:
python 2.7.1
Windows 7
decimal module (inbuilt)

Comment: Did you mean to subtract 2 after rounding?

Comment: Not sure which is the correct answer? Aroth answered my question, but Raymond provided the solution!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, as near as I can determine it, is that `round()` is returning a Python `float` type, and not a `Decimal` type.  Thus it doesn't matter what precision you set on the `decimal` module, because once you call `round()` you no longer have a `Decimal`.

To work around this, you'll probably have to come up with an alternative way to round your numbers that doesn't rely on `round()`.  Such as Raymond's suggestion.

You may find this short ideone example illustrative:  http://ideone.com/xgPL9

Comment: Ofcourse! Just found this snippet from the documentation too... round(a, 1)     # round() first converts to binary floating point

Answer (score 45):

Since *[round()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round)* coerces its input to a regular binary float, the preferred way to round decimal objects is with the *[quantize()](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.quantize)* method:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> d = Decimal('2.000000000000000000001')

>>> d.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -20)     # Round to twenty decimal places
Decimal('2.00000000000000000000')
```

To chop-off the trailing zeros, apply *[normalize()](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.normalize)* to the rounded result:

```
>>> d = Decimal('2.000000000000000000001')
>>> d.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -20).normalize()
Decimal('2')
```

Comment: I did look at this function, but it returns yuck trailing 0s when you round to more decimals than the decimal has (the significant figures, which is sensible). The documentation for decimal says that there are two operations in quantize; the rounding and then the significant figures (or so I've interpreted). Is there are way to just perform the rounding? (Otherwise, I'll just string manipulate away the sig-figs I guess.

Comment: Use string formatting to control the appearance of the decimal:  ``format(Decimal('2.00000000000000000000'), '.1f')`` prints to one decimal place.  You can also convert it to a string and use *rstrip*: ``str(Decimal('2.00000000000000000000')).rstrip('0')``.

Comment: Strip trailing 0s with `Decimal('2.00000000000000000000').normalize()`.

Comment: @AntiEarth: Python 2.7: round() not only converts Decimal to float, it *returns* a float; didn't you notice this? See my answer.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! @John: Somehow I missed it! My code never raised type errors and all my testing was done with the print statement, so decimals and floats came out the same

Answer (score 5):

Try the following...

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP, getcontext

getcontext().prec = 51

def round_as_decimal(num, decimal_places=2):
    """Round a number to a given precision and return as a Decimal

    Arguments:
    :param num: number
    :type num: int, float, decimal, or str
    :returns: Rounded Decimal
    :rtype: decimal.Decimal
    """
    precision = '1.{places}'.format(places='0' * decimal_places)
    return Decimal(str(num)).quantize(Decimal(precision), rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP)

round_as_decimal('2.000000000000000000001', decimal_places=50)
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

Using `round()` for *any* purpose has difficulties:

(1) In Python 2.7, round(Decimal('39.142')) produces 39.14 i.e. a float; 3.2 produces a Decimal.

```
>>> import decimal; round(decimal.Decimal('2.000000000000000000001'),50)
2.0   <<<=== ***float***
```

(2) round() has only one rounding mode; `Decimal.quantize` has many.

(3) For all input types, the single rounding mode changed: Python 2.7 rounds away from 0 (expected in most business applications) whereas Python 3.2 rounds to the nearest even multiple of 10**-n (less expected in business).

Use `Decimal.quantize()`

Answer (score 3):

As stated above, round() returns a float if provided with a Decimal.
For exact calculations, I suggest to do them with not rounded down Decimals, and for rounding the final result, use a function:

```
    def dround(decimal_number, decimal_places):
        return decimal_number.quantize(Decimal(10) ** -decimal_places)
```