# 1 == 2 for large numbers of 1

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm wondering what causes this behaviour. I haven't been able to find an answer that covers this. It is probably something simple and obvious, but it is not to me. I am using `python 2.7.3` in `Ubuntu`.

```
In [1]: 2 == 1.9999999999999999
Out[1]: True

In [2]: 2 == 1.999999999999999
Out[2]: False
```

EDIT:

To clarify my question. Is there a written(in documentation) max number of 9's where python will evaluate the expression above as being equal to 2?

Comment: look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868985/problems-with-rounding-decimals-python

Comment: Oh, the joy of automatic numeric coercions and floating point precision.

Comment: Float values don't have infinite precision and will be rounded eventually.  If you need to control precision look at the `Decimal` module.

Comment: its a problem with how floats are stored internally ... and it is a problem that plagues all languages that have floats

Comment: so, Is the number of 9's needed just arbitrary or you need to have 16 or over (like in this case)?.

Comment: it has to do with whether or not the mantissa can exactly reproduce the parts after the decimal ... eg it cant do `2.2` (if you enter 2.2 at the terminal you will see something like 2.200000002 ... however it __CAN__ handle something like `2.5` fine (notice both have only 1 decimal place when typed)

Comment: The number of `9`s depends on the C `double` size. In most systems it is 64bit, but in other systems it might be bigger or smaller. However in all IEEE-754 compliant machines it will be 64bit. I don't know of machines that are not IEEE-754 compliant. Probably most of these are embedded systems (where you do not want to use Python anyway).

Comment: this will probablyu help you visualize what is happening http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call 1.999999999 a "large 1"

Comment: @Keikoku: well, it's larger than the average 1 ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Python uses floating point representation
- What a floating point actually is, is a fixed-width binary number (called the "significand") plus a small integer to tell you how many powers of two to shift that value by (the "exponent"). Plus a sign bit. Just like scientific notation, but in base 2 instead of 10.
- The closest 64 bit floating point value to `1.9999999999999999` is `2.0`, because 64 bit floating point values (so-called "double precision") uses 52 bits of significand, which is equivalent to about 15 decimal places. So the literal `1.9999999999999999` is just another way of writing `2.0`. However, the closest value to `1.999999999999999` is less than `2.0` (I think it's `1.9999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875` exactly, but I'm too lazy to check that's correct, I'm just relying on Python's formatting code to be exact).
- I don't actually know whether the use specifically of 64 bit floats is required by the Python language, or is an implementation detail of CPython. But whatever size is used, the important thing is not specifically the number of decimal places, it is where the closest floating-point value of that size lies to your decimal literal. It will be closer for some literals than others.

Hence, `1.9999999999999999 == 2` for the same reason that `2.0 == 2` (Python allows mixed-type numeric operations including comparison, and the integer `2` is equal to the float `2.0`). Whereas `1.999999999999999 != 2`.

Comment: this helps to visualize what is happening with the binary repr ... http://www.exploringbinary.com/why-0-point-1-does-not-exist-in-floating-point/

Comment: Thank you all this answers my question. @JoranBeasley The link helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Types coercion

```
>>> 2 == 2.0
True
```

And consequences of maximum number of digits that can be represented in [python](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info) :

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.float_info.dig
15
>>> 1.9999999999999999
2.0
```

more from docs

```
>>> float('9876543211234567')
9876543211234568.0
```

note `..68` on the end instead of expected `..67`

Comment: ok so you need to have `9999999999999999` 16 9's to get the type conversion ?

Comment: @jramirez ah, i thought you wonder about how int can be equal to float

Comment: no it has to do with types of floats ... and if the mantissa can exactly evaluate the part after the decimal

Comment: @alko no, I'm wondering why with 15 9's the equality returns `false`, but with 16 9's it returns `True`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the way floats are implemented in Python. To keep it short and simple: Since floats almost always are an approximation and thus have more digits than most people find useful, the Python interpreter displays a rounded value.

More detailed, floats are stored in binary. This means that they're stored as fractions to the base 2, unlike decimal, were you can display a float as fractions to the base 10. However, most decimal fractions don't have an *exact* representation in binary. Because of that, they are typically stored with a precision of 53 bits. This renders them pretty much useless if you want to do more complex arithmetic operations, since you'll run into some strange problems, e. g.:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>> round(2.675, 2)
2.67
```

See [The docs on floats](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking, 2.0 does equal 1.9999... forever.  They are two different ways of writing the same number.

However, in software, it's important to never compare two floats or decimals for equality - instead, subtract them, take the absolute value, and verify that the (always positive) difference is sufficiently low for your purposes.

EG:

```
if abs(value1 - value2) < 1e10:
   # they are close enough
else:
   # they are not
```

You probably should set EPSILON = 1e10, and use the symbolic constant instead of scattering 1e10 throughout your code, or better still use a comparison function.